# Store Image into Application Root directory Using Java?

Tags: java, spring, io

In my Java Application Storing Image into Folder i'm doing..

```
@RemotingInclude
public void uploadImage(byte[] content,String fileName) {
    try
    {
       fileName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + fileName;
       File f = new File(fileName);  
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);  
       fos.write(content);  
       fos.close();
       System.out.println(f+"   "+fileName);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It is Storing some temp directory ... But i want to Store image into folder Under Application Root directory Because if it is Running on Server only image storing only on Root directory ..

How to Store Image into Folder insted of Temp directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
fileName = context.getRealPath("/<yourfoldername>/" + fileName);
```

Comment: `getContext()` is a stub method to access your servlet context.

Comment: This is not Servlet.. just it is Flex+normal java Program so just it is sample Method..

Comment: did you try `new File("./folder/fileName")` ?

Comment: Now working but it is Storing File Type as "MS-DOS Application"

Comment: if you want `.txt`, then add `.txt` at the end of the string

Comment: Thankyou.... But it always storing Root Directory But i want to Store sub directory of Root directory ..lick this.C:/flex-eclipse/workspace1/EClassV1/Images

Comment: try `new File("./Images/fileName")` instead of `new File("./fileName")`